# 'list' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: matplotlib

I have a dictionary which contains key value pairs lke the below

'''{0: array([171.46000056, 171.46719001, 171.45999844, 179.18608317,
172.39885377, 159.27811113, 170.66230251, 171.73401961,
175.53722754, 170.12924165]),
1: array([192.71797168, 171.46020828, 175.1870201 , 171.7537851 ,
144.34414863, 171.57451004, 195.30462233, 171.60541625,
171.4613451 , 171.46      ]),
10: array([174.97944517, 171.46026679, 171.46020809, 171.1248187 ,
171.451007  , 171.46000035, 175.94311169, 167.19351593,
171.46      , 193.77312368]),
11: array([170.22104398, 171.46000017, 171.57971689, 158.31393312,
171.45999999, 171.46345917, 171.16603842, 169.97842034,
170.76293802, 162.51606652]),
12: array([171.46040601, 171.46000316, 173.25970693, 171.45999994,
188.81233363, 171.45995731, 171.46000081, 171.46172072,
194.77756177, 171.4670961 ]),
13: array([171.45978485, 174.02166567, 174.26865499, 171.46      ,
171.45999677, 171.59310459, 171.45782822, 171.97983166,
171.46      , 171.92189183]),
14: array([165.29966468, 171.35201607, 173.03227433, 171.45810148,
171.46      , 136.77157221, 171.46000023, 171.4594993 ,
178.55450463, 171.2363819 ]),
15: array([170.46665479, 171.45999751, 171.45996082, 147.35608464,
178.17885916, 173.12186109, 170.05003098, 171.4599995 ,
171.45999973, 179.33361937]),
16: array([138.85238633, 171.45780165, 171.46347564, 171.45562802,
179.00816672, 171.32219907, 170.70656828, 185.14075495,
165.79191619, 171.46      ]),
17: array([171.46      , 171.48962078, 166.77414844, 171.46501047,
179.68457266, 171.45715971, 168.26635249, 171.46      ,
178.87164243, 171.45999942]),
18: array([171.54686445, 171.46002029, 171.4197237 , 171.06035103,
171.344059  , 184.76988694, 171.45987776, 171.30432227,
172.54256515, 171.34627756]),
19: array([172.07658981, 154.20269485, 171.46      , 169.60096148,
170.61834356, 171.46291875, 176.49819902, 171.46000006,
171.46193654, 171.45999993]),
2: array([171.57082517, 171.45990539, 169.23799461, 173.11798648,
171.46      , 169.68614664, 171.46934268, 172.07602077,
171.45999639, 171.48454014]),
20: array([171.49175491, 166.29696594, 171.7391187 , 171.46      ,
171.45958226, 171.46000459, 171.48107666, 174.8250891 ,
171.45909185, 171.46      ]),
21: array([173.64012925, 179.7787159 , 163.34578837, 171.45999995,
171.46      , 171.46000015, 179.3299296 , 171.46000048,
171.45998899, 171.46000075]),
22: array([163.83353022, 171.22032808, 171.45996236, 171.45999995,
171.46      , 171.46001107, 172.100737  , 170.2487801 ,
173.17356237, 171.57082221]),
23: array([171.3396972 , 171.45999668, 177.60774002, 171.45996752,
171.46015543, 171.45999853, 153.46715414, 139.02769729,
171.64281885, 171.73561045]),
24: array([174.05146107, 181.45479756, 171.46      , 171.45996487,
171.45867425, 171.50660427, 171.45999936, 158.34382358,
171.43546248, 154.71738645]),
25: array([175.09113264, 171.39875621, 178.6977787 , 171.45357068,
171.46      , 171.45991491, 171.46412172, 170.67625526,
171.6408479 , 171.48365864]),
26: array([171.45999637, 170.24304466, 171.46      , 171.52378365,
171.46      , 171.20128852, 171.46022101, 171.46008849,
170.33278085, 174.04057677]),
27: array([171.46      , 173.00019764, 171.46127353, 171.46      ,
194.52562844, 171.45962937, 171.46      , 171.46000087,
167.90186262, 184.44244711]),
28: array([169.47177139, 171.46      , 175.49147457, 171.46      ,
171.45996795, 171.35433197, 160.05484021, 171.47384633,
179.53982304, 171.46000751]),
29: array([171.47085103, 171.46000001, 173.57720149, 171.45995534,
171.46      , 171.45596307, 170.65166906, 171.4525353 ,
168.06876035, 171.47664885]),
3: array([171.48066676, 176.27717837, 174.63124336, 171.45999541,
173.3813353 , 173.74258525, 171.46      , 171.46      ,
171.51335159, 176.37729139]),
30: array([171.521133  , 171.45995046, 171.45992317, 171.45855946,
172.85165075, 171.46      , 171.45999998, 171.46009145,
171.46000008, 171.46000002]),
31: array([171.46000022, 174.01179912, 171.45910721, 163.99228927,
174.8947032 , 171.46080627, 171.05825529, 171.46000002,
171.45999999, 171.57151546]),
32: array([171.46      , 171.4593126 , 171.46      , 169.63951533,
174.75401553, 155.15859255, 171.50586253, 174.06563085,
171.45999995, 171.46      ]),
33: array([171.46      , 171.43466207, 171.45991494, 171.46      ,
171.45859905, 171.71364684, 171.4596084 , 171.18573479,
171.45741213, 171.41125109]),
34: array([196.31763196, 171.46      , 195.0970548 , 171.46056861,
174.12045887, 171.45839547, 164.9746245 , 171.46      ,
169.23472174, 191.4176025 ]),
35: array([163.19026071, 175.05999077, 171.46054355, 175.89865791,
171.46      , 182.72884827, 171.46002444, 171.45999975,
171.46000005, 171.46000222]),
36: array([171.46000023, 171.88123998, 171.46      , 169.35996958,
171.3807261 , 171.07022275, 171.45983342, 171.46092126,
171.45999964, 183.86481555]),
37: array([153.07689317, 171.41861864, 179.2210372 , 171.45987967,
171.46000004, 165.00847776, 174.90451004, 171.45999873,
174.63692058, 163.13707928]),
38: array([171.46      , 171.46057751, 171.46      , 165.52760233,
171.46      , 165.48586134, 171.47739169, 171.45999997,
171.46075765, 171.43433173]),
39: array([171.91584821, 171.46002524, 171.45160618, 171.46      ,
172.21739234, 177.37558356, 171.4560661 , 166.60869847,
171.41625144, 175.8535176 ]),
4: array([171.45988058, 171.0927479 , 171.46743887, 171.50582212,
171.46001106, 175.82498846, 165.42536707, 171.51066773,
171.46      , 167.12568745]),
40: array([171.46003336, 171.45999903, 174.80222249, 162.85118337,
174.7274036 , 165.79814015, 171.46      , 171.46000004,
171.45999996, 173.75881437]),
41: array([171.52068895, 171.46000716, 172.24749003, 173.91359521,
171.46000049, 171.44011769, 171.46      , 171.46001667,
171.46      , 169.64838303]),
42: array([171.46006257, 171.46001308, 163.1485692 , 178.51890798,
165.90983961, 171.45636223, 165.39908959, 172.21291542,
170.16698877, 171.57320833]),
43: array([170.40174377, 169.772407  , 171.46000549, 171.46090427,
171.45976094, 171.69316006, 171.3437967 , 172.96559946,
171.45999984, 171.46      ]),
44: array([167.59496574, 171.45999996, 171.46002579, 171.45845516,
171.46000004, 171.45999884, 171.460001  , 171.45827869,
171.4599963 , 173.22729389]),
45: array([171.46000009, 171.46      , 171.46429262, 171.45998982,
171.46      , 198.28636544, 171.31567251, 171.54561504,
171.45998311, 150.24330563]),
46: array([171.34518753, 171.46      , 176.5947665 , 171.46      ,
171.4632759 , 171.47403739, 170.1047552 , 171.46000003,
171.46      , 171.47865801]),
47: array([171.46      , 171.45999414, 171.45998286, 171.46000648,
176.57966743, 171.46      , 174.16819475, 169.772887  ,
178.58748472, 173.01556557]),
48: array([171.48354393, 168.29123257, 168.45848925, 170.41894069,
171.46      , 171.45355849, 171.45999637, 171.46      ,
173.90900419, 171.46      ]),
49: array([175.10563294, 181.37747207, 174.2174603 , 173.44696277,
164.4938343 , 171.45975897, 171.4599994 , 171.35057128,
137.38512237, 171.45970585]),
5: array([171.84275434, 171.34774441, 173.27092442, 171.45987536,
171.47970477, 171.46000896, 171.43461906, 171.46343378,
169.52794317, 171.46      ]),
6: array([171.36882497, 179.06278175, 173.01330009, 177.0849784 ,
171.46000002, 171.46000318, 171.50259625, 171.45999989,
147.39613812, 171.66431078]),
7: array([171.46      , 171.45906203, 171.81233143, 171.46      ,
180.71737173, 171.56892459, 171.46218517, 174.6703085 ,
172.14706743, 171.65377333]),
8: array([174.46189282, 171.46      , 173.59626439, 171.45999521,
172.5394941 , 189.77229154, 171.46000042, 171.46006682,
174.05812853, 171.45999529]),
9: array([156.76882392, 171.46002968, 163.13420913, 171.45999999,
171.46031089, 171.45999296, 171.57582149, 171.08216417,
188.34185211, 171.4600001 ]),
'best': [159.27811113466888,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
144.34414862872876,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163,
136.77157220633163]}'''

so i extracted the key value best from the dictinary and plot it and stored it in a variable
z = plt.plot(a['best'])
but while i am doing z.show() its giving me above error

Comment: Please give a minimum reproducable example of the code you tried and what your problems are with it, including error messages and expected outputs. SO does not support questions in the form of "Write me a program". This way you will receive quick and effective help. Look here to learn more about this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wanted to extract the best key-value pair from the dictionary so I extracted and kept it in z and I wanted to plot it too so I did it using z = plt.plot(a['best']) but while I am doing z.show() it's stating me " 'list' object has no attribute 'show' "